# XAML Chart not populating Line Series despite binding to correct data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

I am using the Chart in System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit and binding to an object of type

```
ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>>
```

I have my chart set up as in the picture below, and the screenshot has me hovering over the binding source so I know it is binding to the right object. But when I run the program the Chart is completely blank. I know this setup works, I use the exact same code in another program and it works perfectly. The only things I can think of is some missing references or somehow the style of the line not being set.

[image]

**Edit:**

Here is my code, it is a Runge-Kutta differential equation solver. I included the line you gave me near the bottom.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>> points = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>>();

    private double function(double t, double y)
    {
        return y + t;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        points.Clear();
        points.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, double>(0, 1));
        double h = .01;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            double k1 = function(points[i].Key, points[i].Value);
            double k2 = function(points[i].Key + (h / 2.0), points[i].Value + (h / 2.0) * k1);
            double k3 = function(points[i].Key + (h / 2.0), points[i].Value + (h / 2.0) * k2);
            double k4 = function(points[i].Key + h, points[i].Value + h * k3);
            double t = points[i].Key + h;
            double y = points[i].Value + (h / 6.0) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4);

            points.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, double>(t, y));
        }

        chart.DataContext = points;
    }
```

**Edit (solved):**

I refactored into an MVVM project and it works perfectly now. So the moral is, stay away from code behind, even on tiny side projects.

Comment: Just for curiosity... Why do you use KeyValuePair into an ObservableCollection. Why not an ObservableCollection of "System.Windows.Point"? You can use independent : "x" and "y" as dependant. Usually we use KeyValuePair with a Dictionary. But a Dictionnary it is not Observable. You would require to be Observable, in your case, only if you add/remove any node from your collection after you change your DataContext. Also, you should take a look at MVVM, my experience tell me that it is a must.

Comment: Yes, the suggestion of MVVM is right on the money, when I refactored into MVVM the chart populated perfectly. And thank you for the suggestion of using Point, when I have done it before people have told me "that is a UI concept and you should keep it out of your View Model"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

In your `Window_Loaded` event:

```
  chart.DataContext = points;
```

In your XAML:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart" Margin="0" Title="Chart Title">
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Full code:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>> points = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            points.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, double>(i, r.NextDouble()));

        chart1.DataContext = points;
    }
}
```

This is the chart using your points:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I put that code in the method that adds the points and I got an System.InvalidOperationException saying "Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress". Then a couple seconds later the points loaded but the x-axis was completely collapsed so the points laid on a vertical line.

Comment: Also take `DataContext` out of your XAML.

Comment: I did, and posted the C# code behind. For this I am putting the code behind in the window

Comment: See the result i got using points from your formula. Looks good.

Comment: Okay there has to be something going on with this project, I think I will build another project from scratch using the MVVM framework instead of code behind and see if that works, thank you.

Comment: did you take out `DataContext` from your XAML like i said before?

Comment: I did, yes. It did not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the green check, Sir !!

Comment: Thank you, knowing that the charts works minus DataContext helps, I think a rebuild using a better setup will help.